# Faded Status Bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios7, fade, ios7-statusbar

In Facebook's new app, Facebook Paper, there is a status bar that is slightly faded out (the text is somewhat faded out). I've tried several different methods but they haven't worked. Any ideas on how to replicate this? Below is a screen shot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8Pzc.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ***highly*** doubt it's faded. It's most likely that the dark blue accents on the rest of the page make it seem as if it is faded. If it was fading the status bar, it would have to be using private API's and even Facebook can't get past Apple's strict rules.

Comment: That sucks :( Hope iOS 8 has the ability to do that.

Comment: Maybe. But IMHO I think it would confuse most users, new and old. They are used to Status bar or no status bar, nothing in between.